# cannot use state params variable

Tags: angularjs, lodash

I'm retrieving id in url like that :

```
  var id=$stateParams.carId;
```

with

```
  console.log(id)
```

i'm getting the right value : 91
The problem is : when i try to use this value with lodash i get "undefined":

```
 console.log(id) //91
 var result = _.find(modules, {id: id});
 console.log(result); //undefined
```

but by using directly the value : 91, I'm getting the object i'm looking for

```
console.log(id) //91
var result = _.find(modules, {id: 91});
console.log(result); //it works
```

In modules i have

```
 console.log(modules)// Array[244]
```

where the element i'm looking for is :

```
manager:John
user:Marc
documentation: Array[0]
id: 91
```

Comment: What's in modules, can you console.log that out and show us?

Comment: I just edited the post with 'modules'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly Check the datatype of $stateParams.carId.

I suppose $stateParams.carId is of type String hence it is not able to find the appropriate value from the modules.

```
typeof($stateParams.carId)
```

Use above command to check the Datatype

Comment: I got this : string

Comment: Which means they are different datatypes and it cannot match it. You can try any one of these 1. Change the Datatype of $stateParams.carId to Number (or) 2. use parseInt to convert it to a Number `_.find(modules, {id: parseInt(id)});`

Comment: Try parsing the value as an interger like so var result = _.find(modules, {id: parseInt(id)}) or a better way is to fix your data so it is the correct datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = _.find(modules, { id: _.get($stateParams, 'carId') });
```

But also, I'd like to see what is in modules? Can you console.log() that out please?

Comment: I still have 'undefined'. I have edited my post with 'modules'